# Platform.sh fails to build locally. It can't find project files

Tags: build, local, platform

I am experimenting with Platform.sh, and trying to build my project locally following their [documentation](https://docs.platform.sh/gettingstarted/local.html).
But the build fails, apparently it can't find the project files:

```
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

I have tried `git commit` the code beforehand, but still no luck. Here is the full traceback I get:

```
$ platform local:build                                                                                   Mon 11 Feb 2019 12:28:09 -02
Building application app (runtime type: python:3.6)
Installing python3 dependencies with 'pip': pipenv
Looking in indexes: http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/+simple/
Collecting pipenv==2018.10.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/+f/d5a/c9a7705c654ec/pipenv-2018.10.13-py3-none-any.whl (5.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.2MB 37.8MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/space-app-phFju0DF/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv==2018.10.13->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (10.0.1)
Collecting certifi (from pipenv==2018.10.13->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/+f/993/f830721089fef/certifi-2018.11.29-py2.py3-none-any.whl (154kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 36.9MB/s 
Collecting virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 (from pipenv==2018.10.13->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/+f/f2a/07ed255f3abac/virtualenv_clone-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/space-app-phFju0DF/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv==2018.10.13->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (39.1.0)
Collecting virtualenv (from pipenv==2018.10.13->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/+f/8b9/abfc51c38b70f/virtualenv-16.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.0MB 34.0MB/s 
Installing collected packages: certifi, virtualenv-clone, virtualenv, pipenv
  The script virtualenv-clone is installed in './bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script virtualenv is installed in './bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in './bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed certifi-2018.11.29 pipenv-2018.10.13 virtualenv-16.4.0 virtualenv-clone-0.5.1
Running post-build hooks
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Backing up previous build to: /home/user/Dev/space-app/.platform/local/builds/default-old.tar.gz
Creating symbolic links to mimic shared file mounts
  Symlinking logs to .platform/local/shared/logs

Build complete for application app
Web root: /home/user/Dev/space-app/_www

Cleaning up...
```

## EDIT

I am adding my `.platform.app.yaml`:

```
name: 'app'

type: 'python:3.6'

dependencies:
    python3:
        pip: '19.0.2'
        # pipenv: '2018.10.13'

relationships:
    database: "postgresqldb:postgresql"

web:
    upstream:
        socket_family: unix
    commands:
        start: "gunicorn -w 4 -b unix:$SOCKET myapp.wsgi:application"
    locations:
        "/":
            passthru: true
        "/static":
            root: "static"
            expires: 1h
            allow: true

disk: 512

mounts:
    'logs':
        source: local
        source_path: logs

hooks:
    build: |
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        # pipenv install --system --deploy

        mkdir logs
        python manage.py collectstatic
        rm -rf logs
    deploy: |
        python manage.py migrate
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `find . -regex '.*requirements.txt$'` give you?

Comment: `find . -regex '.*requirements.txt$'`

./requirements.txt

./.platform/local/deps/python3/requirements.txt

Comment: What's in your build hook? What happens when you run it yourself instead of using `platform build`?

Comment: Royall, I only have the `pip install -r requirements.txt` instruction. Apparently I need to change dir before running it. I am reading the docs again, because there seems to be something else I am missing: https://docs.platform.sh/configuration/app/build.html#hooks.
Running my app locally/manually works well.
I would expect the same .platform.app.yaml to work both locally and remotely though.

Answer (score 1):

I would very much suggest getting some sort of virtualenv running.. and as you are already installing pipenv... I would not mix system python and this project's python...

The following should work nicely both locally and on the server...

```
hooks:
    build: |
        pipenv install -r requirements.txt
        pipenv run python manage.py collectstatic
    deploy: |
        pipenv run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I understand all that and thank you for your reply, but I am comfortable with Python. The problem is a different one, for some reason the working directory is not the project folder, but instead: `project_dir/.platform/local/builds/default-tmp`, which inside only has a symlink named public to the actual project dir, i.e: `public -> ../../../..`, reason why it can't find any requirements.txt. Any other ideas?